# Expected value of a variable with piecewise pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

If I have that the pdf of a variable is:
$$f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2},  & \text{if $y=0$} \\
\frac{1}{4a},  & \text{if $a<y<2a$} \\
\frac{1}{4a}, & \text{if 4a<y<5a}\\
0, & OW
\end{cases}$$ where $a>0$ constant, how can I find the Expected value of Y? In particular I am not sure how to handle the part where y=0.

Comment: This is not a valid pdf, since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y)\,dy=\frac12$. Setting $f_Y(0)=\frac12$ does not add any mass to the integral.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Since Y is discrete and continuous we have that that $\frac{1}{2} + \int_a^{2a}\frac{1}{4a} + \int_{4a}^{5a} \frac{1}{4a} =1$

Answer (score 2):

You need to use sums for the parts where $Y$ is discrete, and integrate over parts where $Y$ is continuous. The formula you need to use here is
$$\Bbb{E}[Y]=f_{Y}(0)\times 0 + \int_{a}^{2a} yf_{Y} (y)\, dy + \int_{4a}^{5a}yf_{Y}(y)\, dy.$$

Comment: I though the first summand would be $\int_0^0 yf_Y(y)\,dy$. Setting $f_Y(0)=\frac12$ is not equivalent to putting a mass of $\frac12$ at $0$. In fact, $f_Y(y)$ is not a valid pdf, as it integrates to $\frac12$.

Comment: OK. I interpreted it as $Y$ has mass $1/2$ at $0$ and is continuous in the other regions. If so, it's a valid pdf and the expectation is using the above formula.